# Value doesn't appear after event occurs in React JS

Tags: reactjs

I have an input where i can add many values.

demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-bush-jy1n9?file=/example.js

I wrote :

```js
    export default class CreatableInputOnly extends Component<*, State> {
  state = {
    inputValue: "",
    value: []
  };
  handleChange = (value: any, actionMeta: any) => {
    console.group("Value Changed");
    console.log(value);
    console.log(`action: ${actionMeta.action}`);
    console.groupEnd();
    this.setState({ value });
  };
  handleInputChange = (inputValue: string) => {
    this.setState({ inputValue });
  };
  handleKeyDown = (event: SyntheticKeyboardEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
    const { inputValue, value } = this.state;
    if (!inputValue) return;
    switch (event.key) {
      case "Enter":
        console.log("vvvv", value);
      case "Tab":
        console.group("Value Added");
        console.log(value);
        console.groupEnd();
        this.setState({
          inputValue: "",
          value: [...value, createOption(inputValue)]
        });

        event.preventDefault();
    }
  };
  render() {
    const { inputValue, value } = this.state;
    return (
      <CreatableSelect
        components={components}
        inputValue={inputValue}
        isClearable
        isMulti
        menuIsOpen={false}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        onInputChange={this.handleInputChange}
        onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown}
        placeholder="Type something and press enter..."
        value={value}
      />`enter code here`
);
  }
}
```

When i write a value in input and after  that click on enter then the value does not appears here:  console.log("vvvv", value);, i have to add again a value and again to push enter. How to get the actual values in that function?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the switch statement in a correct way. The Codesandbox website even tells you what to actually. You need breaks and a default statement.

```
handleKeyDown = (event: SyntheticKeyboardEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
const { inputValue, value } = this.state;
if (!inputValue) return;
switch (event.key) {
  case "Enter":
    console.log("vvvv", inputValue);
    break;
  case "Tab":
    this.setState({
      inputValue: "",
      value: [...value, createOption(inputValue)]
    });
    console.group("Value Added");
    console.log(inputValue);
    console.groupEnd();
    break;
  default:
}
```

};

/EDIT:

I just changed the value to inputValue :)

Comment: I put it here for you: https://codesandbox.io/s/withered-https-zipkt?file=/example.js
If you press enter, the text will be console.logged, if you press tab, the text will be added. whats the functionality you actually want?

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason it doesn't work is the state value you are trying to output is being controlled by the input change, and input change holds an object. So, basically if you return the input change's value instead, you can see print what is in the textbox. Also, remember setState is asynchronous

```
 switch (event.key) {
      case "Enter":
        console.log("vvvv", createOption(inputValue).value);
      case "Tab":
        console.group("Value Added");
        console.log(value);
        console.groupEnd();
        this.setState({
          inputValue: "",
          value: [...value, createOption(inputValue)]
        });

        event.preventDefault();
    }
```

Comment: do you know how to get value inside `handleKeyDown`?

Comment: this is inside handleKeyDown @Asking. You mean what is being typed in the input? You can grab the input value in handleInputChange the same way

Comment: i agree, but i need the access to the `event` from `handlekeydown` function, it exist a solution?

Comment: sorry not sure what you trying to achieve? Can you elaborate on that please? @Asking